# Unable to handle setEditing method through UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have added a bar button item in my tool bar and I implemented its functionality in the method given below. I am not able, however, to display a delete button in each row. How can I do this?

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing
         animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing
             animated:animated];
    [editButton setEnabled:!editing];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSString *selectedFile =  (NSString*) [directoryContents objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedPath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:selectedFile];
    BOOL canWrite = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isWritableFileAtPath:selectedPath];
    if(!canWrite)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"status"
                                message:@"path isnt writable" 
                                delegate:nil 
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    NSError *err = nil;
    if(! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:selectedPath error:&err])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"status"
                                                        message:@"cannot delete"
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];

    }
    // Delete the row from the data source.
    NSArray *deletedPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath];
    [self loadDirectoryContents];
    [self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deletedPaths withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button on the toolbar will need to be connected to an interface action in the custom table view controller subclass. Define the action as follows -

```
- (IBAction)startEditing {
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing
         animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing
             animated:animated];
    [editButton setEnabled:!editing];
}
```

---

You will have to implement the delegate method [`tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW23) and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` for the rows you wish to enable it.

Comment: How did you create the button? Can you put that code in the problem?

Comment: i manually add the button in tool bar in IB. and set its connection to IBOutlet in header.

Comment: How did you wire it up. Did you assign a method to be called when the button is clicked? What does that method do?

Comment: i didnt set any method when that button is clicked.. only i do [editButton setEnabled:!editing]; in setEditing method. "editButton" is the UIBarButtonItem. plz reffer to above code

Comment: Ok so the button is getting disabled when you click on it.

Comment: when i click on it do not show delete button before every row

Comment: what about the button? Is it being disabled?

Comment: So the method is not being called. Its as simple as that. Actually you will need to attach the button to an `IBAction`. You should redefine your current `setEditing:animated:` to something like `(IBAction)startEditing` and connect it to the button

Comment: what i have to write in this method?

Comment: controll is not shifting to delegate method.